# How to declare a c# variable for a picked item from a combobox

Tags: c#, variables, serial-port, global-variables

How do I create a public variable for a selected value in my comboBox1 so that it can be used in every button so I don't have to repeat it for every button?  For every button I have:

```
var portNum = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort( portNum, 9600, Parity.None, 8))
```

But I want to just have portNum and not have to put the var declaration line in every button.

```
public partial class planar232 : Form
{
    private SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();
    private string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();


    public planar232()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var portNum = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort( portNum, 9600, Parity.None, 8))
        {
            byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[9] { 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x73, 0x21, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D };
            port.Open();
            port.Write(bytesToSend, 0, 9);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var portNum = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort( portNum, 9600, Parity.None, 8))
        {
            byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[9] { 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x73, 0x21, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x0D };
            port.Open();
            port.Write(bytesToSend, 0, 9);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your ComboBox is just displaying "COM1", etc, do this:

```
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, 9600, Parity.None, 8))
```

Or, if you need to use `SelectedItem`,

```
using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), 9600, Parity.None, 8))
```

If you really want a property,

```
string SelectedPort { get { return comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); } }
```

---

Better yet, refactor your code to just specify the data in the button handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[9] { 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x73, 0x21, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D };
    this.Send(bytesToSend);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[9] { 0x38, 0x30, 0x31, 0x73, 0x21, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x0D };
    this.Send(bytesToSend);
}

private void Send(byte[] bytesToSend)
{
    var portNum = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort( portNum, 9600, Parity.None, 8))
    {
        port.Open();
        port.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the property in the form scope:

```
public Form Form1
{
    public string PortNum {get;set;}

    public void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       PortNum = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    ... (rest of your code)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx):

```
// this is a class member
string PortNum 
{
    get { return comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
}

// instead of your original code
using (var port = new SerialPort(PortNum, ...)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable Buttons 1 and 2 at design time.

add a private member PortNum

Add a SelectedItemChange Event handler to the combobox
In that if the selection is not null, save it in PortNum and enable the buttons